# How to make Qt programs look good under Xfce?

Tags: themes, gtk, xubuntu, xfce, qt

I use Xfce.

My problem is - some programs look nice and some sort of ugly. AFAIK this is because Xfce is GTK and most programs use GTK theme, but some programs use Qt and thus don't use GTK themes.

So - my question is - How can I apply some theme to these Qt programs? Can I download some qt theme and drop into ~/.themes? would that work? Qt programs don't have to look absolutely the same as GTK ones - I don't care about that. But I want them at least not to look so ugly.:)

[image]

Comment: Correction: VLC uses Qt not GTK.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer to your question but if you want a nice, consistent and unified look for both Qt and GTK programs I recommend the QtCurve style. Modern distributions should provide a package, in Ubuntu it's `apt-get install qtcurve`.

And yes, `qtconfig` is the program to use for configuring Qt-related stuff.
In Ubuntu 16.04 you can install it via `apt install qt4-qtconfig`.

Comment: i see.. Didn't now about qtCurve - thanks.

Answer (score 8):

ok. sorted.

simply run qtconfig and select different look.

Answer (score 7):

Put this in `~/.bashrc`. It works with Qt 5 and Gtk+ 3:

```
export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk
```

Answer (score 6):

Excuse the slight self-promotion but I wrote a blog post and script to ensure QGtkEngine finds the correct GTK style:
http://mikemcquaid.com/2011/12/01/make-qt-use-the-gtk-style-on-xfce-or-xubuntu/

Answer (score 5):

If QT4 apps don't look good, then do the following and your GTK theme will be used:

In terminal type:

`gconftool-2 --set --type string /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme your-theme-name`

then edit the `~/.xinitrc` file and add the following line:

`export GTK2_RC_FILES="$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0"`

Answer (score 4):

for QT5 just install qt5ct and run